# Is there a term in graph theory called 'GRAIL'?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, information-theory

I've been a talk with a PhD student about some graph issue and told me about GRAIL graph and have drawn it for me as you see in the picture, however, I try to generalize so-called "Grail graph" to k-pair problem. But I am not able to find a definition, though.

In the picture is an example of 2-pair problem in the GRAIL graph.

http://postimg.org/image/4a3xvsik9/

so my question is: have you seen this kind of graph? or have you heard about this graph, or do you know a name for this graph (may be I misunderstood with this kind of graph).

I have to point that I found a paper called "GRAIL: Scalable Reachability Index for Large Graphs". However, it doesn't give me an example of a graph, instead it just give me a "a good scale for reachability graph between fixed two nodes";

Thank you.

Comment: ummmm, the Holy Grail was an item searched for by King Arthur and his knights. In any field of science, you could refer to some theorem to be proved or some example to be found as the holy grail for that subject. So, in physics, they sometimes refer to the God Particle. Put it all together, there are probably plenty of things that have been referred to as The Grail in mathematics, and others in future. You will need to ask your friend about the history of the problem.

Comment: "**GRAIL**: Scalable **R**eachability **I**ndex for **L**arge **G**raphs" ... just sayin'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there is a graph called **GRAIL GRAPH**.

I have found it first by trial-and-error searching technique among many papers of Network (branch of graph theory) and Information theory, a [paper](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~chihw/pub_pdf/07C_ISIT_LNC.pdf) is published and written by C. Wang and N. B. Shroff. Moreover, I received a couple days ago an email from my friend telling me the reference for the name of the Grail graph and he sent me the same paper that I found.

Comment: Thank you for the literature.. if you want more about Network Coding, go look at these pages:  (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/surveys-on-network-coding) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_network_coding)